# How to display a custom block above "product tags" block in product detail view page?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, custom, frontend, cms

Magento 1.9.x

I've added some code to the `catalog.xml` file under `catalog/product_view` block and I can see my custom block appear in the product detail view page. 
 However, it's displayed below the **product tags** block.

What do I have to do in order to get my block appear above the **product tags** block and not below?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure the block shares the same parent as the product tags, and then you can use the `before=""` attribute in your layout XML.

The value of `before=""` will need to be the same block name as the product tags.

If I'm thinking of the same tags as you this'll be:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="your/block_type" name="your.block.name" template="your/template.phtml" before="tags_popular"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: I can see the block appear in the product view page when I add the lines to catalog.xml file between reference=content tags. It appears under the content though. And I can't find anything related to product tags in this catalog.xml. Could I find product tags somewhere else?

Comment: Yeah, they're defined in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/tag.xml`